# Copy a subset of a column, based on conditions, to another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable

I have very limited R skills, and after hours searching for a solution I could not see an option that would work.
I have several large data tables. From each one, I would like to copy part of a column into an dataframe, to populate a column there.
My data tables (tabn1, tabn2, tabn3) all have the same format, but with different lengths. Each subset will have a different number of rows. I would want empty spaces to be filled with NA. I can't even copy the first column, so the subsequent are the next problem!

```
Ro  Co  Red Green   Yellow
1   3   123 999 265
1   3   223 875 5877
1   4   21488   555 478
1   4   558 23698   5558
2   3   558 559 148
2   3   4579    557 59
2   4   1489    545 2369
2   4   123 999 265
3   3   558 559 148
3   3   558 23698   5558
3   4   4579    557 59
3   4   1478 4579   557
4   3   1488    555 478
4   3   1478    2945    5889
4   4   448 259 4548
4   4   26576   158 15
```

My new data frame col names:

```
cls <- c("n1","n2","n3")
```

I created a dataframe with the column names:

```
df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol=3)),cls)
```

For each of my tables, I want to subset Ro > = 3, Co = 3, column "Red" only
I have tried:

```
sub1 <- (filter(tabn1, tabn1$Ro >=3 | tabn$Co == 3)
df$n1 <- sub1$Red

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, n1, value = c(183.94, 180.884,  : 
  replacement has 32292 rows, data has 1
```

Also:

```
df$n1 <- cut(sub1$Red)

> Error in cut.default(sub1$Red) : 
  argument "breaks" is missing, with no default
```

I tried using df as a datatable instead of dataframe, but also got the following errors:

```
df <- setNames(data.table(matrix(ncol=3)),cls)
df$n1 <- sub1$Red
> Error in set(x, j = name, value = value) : 
  Supplied 32292 items to be assigned to 1 items of column 'nn1'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

I would subsequently tried to subset and copy from tabn2 to df$n2, and so forth. As indicated above, the original tables have different lengths.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You created 'df' with 1 row and then you are assigning the filtered data with multiple rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the number of rows in 'df' and 'sub1' are different.  'df' is created with 1 row.  Instead, we can create the 'df' directly from the 'sub1' itself

```
df <- sub1['Red']
names(df) <- cls[1]
```

---

Also, another way to create the data.frame, would be to specify the `nrow` as well

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = nrow(sub1), ncol = length(cls)),
       dimnames = list(NULL, cls))
```

Regarding the second error with `cut`, it needs `breaks`.  Either we specify the number of breaks

```
cut(sub1$Red, breaks = 3)
```

Or a vector of break points

```
cut(sub1$Red, breaks = c(-Inf, 100, 500, 1000, Inf))
```

---

If there are many 'tabn' objects, get them into a `list`, loop over the `list` with `lapply`

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = '^tabn\\d+$'))
out_lst <- lapply(lst1, function(x) subset(x, Ro >=3 | Co == 3)$Red)
```

It is possible that after `subset`ting and selecting the 'Red' column, the number of elements may be different.  If the `lengths` are different, a option is to pad `NA` at the end for those having lesser number of elements before `cbind`ing it

```
mx <- max(lengths(out_lst))
df <- do.call(cbind, lapply(out_lst, `length<-`, mx))
```

Comment: Please see my edits above. the original data tables have different lengths. As I am doing multiple subsets, I don't know what the length of each subset from each table will be to be able to define the number of rows a priori. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisDias you can get all the datasets into a `list` as in the updated solution

Comment: But then from the ```out_lst``` how do I get each of the ```$Red``` into a separate column in a dataframe?

Comment: @ChrisDias If the datasets have different number of rows from subsetting, then it is better to store as a `list` because a single data.frame needs to have the same length of rows

Comment: @ChrisDias I updated the solution.  Please check